# ImageMagick on Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 7.0

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7, imagick

I have been going around in circles trying to find the correct combination to install Imagick on a Bitnami image running Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 7.0.

If I try using `sudo pecl install imagick`, then the build fails with

```
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_defs.h:29:31: fatal error: wand/MagickWand.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <wand/MagickWand.h>
```

I have tried to install with `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` and then do get an imagick,so that I can include it in my php.ini. However, when I try to use it, I see the following in PHP info and am obviously unable to process anything:

`imagemagick number of supported formats 0`

After a half day lost trying to do what I thought would take a few minutes, I am reaching out for any and all advice!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**In Ubuntu**

***1st method:***

First install imagemagick

`sudo apt install imagemagick`

and then install the php-imagick

`sudo apt install php-imagick`

now restart your web server.

***2nd method (using pecl):***

Run

`sudo apt install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick php-dev`

`sudo pecl install imagick`

now restart your web server.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these are trying to install php7.1 which I cannot do. How can I force this to only install a php 7.0 version of imagik? thanks

Answer (score 0):

To install php-imagick for specific version, use

```
sudo apt-get install php[version]-imagick
```

So in this case, it should be

```
sudo apt-get install php7-imagick
```